# Can I change current stacktrace in C#?

Tags: c#, mono, unity-game-engine

In short, I need to modify the current stack trace in C#, so that method that I call (which I cannot modify) would think that it was someone else who called it.

Now, to give a little context about why I need to do such a horrible hack.

In Unity3d, [Debug.Log](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.Log.html) creates a new record in developer console. When you double-click it, it opens the IDE to show exact file and line that was responsible for that record. However, for various reasons (disable debug in production, make it usable in other threads) I created a wrapper class `Print` that I use instead of UnityEngine.Debug.

But with wrapper, now when a developer clicks on the log record in console, it is `Print` that gets opened, not the actual place where `Print.Log` was called. And since `Debug.Log` does it regardless of the error message or context object, I figured that it uses call stack to identify the file to open. Needless to say, I want to fix that.

Comment: As I do understand the motivation for you to do this. I think it is not possible because it would make it possible to circumvent any code access security concept

Comment: I think that too, but I had to ask to be sure.

Comment: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/176422/debug-wrapper-class.html found this link, recommends moving your debug class to a different assembly.

Comment: @SirBraneDamuj I can confirm that suggestion works, it's how my logger works.

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe it is possible. Looking at the source code of [`Environment.StackTrace`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/environment.cs#26a4d661c01be4f8#references) and the subsequent [`GetStackTrace()`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/environment.cs#1467) call we can see it [creates the stacktrace](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/diagnostics/stacktrace.cs#381) each time whenever it is called. Since there doesn't seem to be anything you could inject to change some of its working, I think it's safe to conclude that you cannot change the stacktrace without modifying how it is called.

If you would have the possibility to do that, you could use something like this which comes down to retrieving the current stacktrace and using reflection to change the most recent [`StackFrame`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/diagnostics/stackframe.cs#26)'s `method` field to mimic what it is you're after.

```
void Main()
{
    DoSomething();
}

void DoSomething(){
    Console.WriteLine (Environment.StackTrace); // Last frame: at System.Environment.GetStackTrace(Exception e, Boolean needFileInfo)

    var frames = new StackTrace().GetFrames();
    var lastframe = frames[0]; // last frame: DoSomething at offset 100 in file:line:column <filename unknown>:0:0
    var methodField = lastframe.GetType().GetField("method", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    var redirectedMethod = typeof(Redirect).GetMethod("RedirectToMethod", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
    methodField.SetValue(lastframe, redirectedMethod);
    Console.WriteLine (frames); // last frame: RedirectToMethod at offset 100 in file:line:column <filename unknown>:0:0
    Console.WriteLine (Environment.StackTrace); // last frame: at System.Environment.GetStackTrace(Exception e, Boolean needFileInfo)
}

public class Redirect {
    public void RedirectToMethod() { }
}
```

But once again: this is very brittle and not applicable in your current situation. What you are trying to do is fairly exotic and should probably be avoided altogether.

As to an actual solution: I'm afraid I don't have any experience with Unity so I can only google but [this thread](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/debug-log-and-needless-spam.38720/) might be interesting to you. I referred to .NET sources here but you can find [very similar code](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/System.Diagnostics/StackTrace.cs) in the Mono source ofcourse.

Answer (score 4):

A work around to this, is compile your Print class into a unity compatible Dll (.Net 2 I think). When doubling clicking on the log, the console will ignore the dll information and go to where Print was called.